# MySite Newsfeed: Follow without Permission

Tags: permissions, mysite, newsfeed

Users can see Newsfeeds from pages they follow even without access permission to the page.

When a user follows a page and afterwards his access permission is revoked he can still see all old and new messages of this site.

I found this technet article: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn167721.aspx

> If a user’s permission to a URL changes from access granted to access
>   denied within the long TTL cached period, the feed item will still
>   appear in the user’s feed. However, the user will be unable to open
>   the URL because SharePoint security prevents users from accessing
>   information that they do not have permission to. After the long TTL
>   period expires, the security trimming process repeats and the cached
>   item will be updated to access denied so the feed item no longer
>   appears.

I tried to fix this by setting the "SecTrimCacheMaxTTLMinutes" to one hour but the new and old messages still appear 10 hours later.

Is this a known Newsfeed bug or could it be a problem with the "User Profile service application"?